# Why is the layout full-width despite setting contentSize and wideSize/

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-block-theme

I have added layout object and properties contentSize : 620px , wideSize : 1000px in my theme.json but still the layout on front end as well as in the editor is full width

In the editor I can see my set values under layout tab but I cannot see its effect niether in the editor nor on the front end

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/wp/6.2/theme.json",
  "settings": {
    "appearanceTools": false,
    "layout": {
      "contentSize": "620px",
      "wideSize": "1000px"
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to Local dev site](https://terrific-suit.localsite.io/)
If prompted, enter the information below.
Username: saxophone
Password: clever

[Screen Shot of the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRxj8.png)

[Screen Shot of layout tab in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh33U.png)

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you add blocks inside **Group** block then the child blocks stays under content width.

Nested blocks use content width with options for full and wide widths.
By enabling the layout setting "Inner blocks use content width" would help.
Check the screenshot - [Inner blocks use content width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXciO.png).